# Read out dxTextBox input value

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core-mvc, devextreme

I have a strange problem using ASP.NET MVC Core with DevExtreme components:

Here I have a simple DevExtreme dxTextBox. When the user types an input in the textbox and hits the enter key, the javascript method "showPopup" will be called with the parameter 'Kunde'.

```
            <div class="dx-field">
                <div class="dx-field-label">Kunde</div>
                <div class="dx-field-value">
                    @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBox()
                        .ID("textBoxKunde")
                        .OnEnterKey("function(e) { showPopup('Kunde') }")
                        .Placeholder("Name und/oder Vorname des Kunden eingeben...")
                        )
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now here is the JavaScript-Code:

```
<script>
function showPopup(e) {
    switch(e) {
        case 'Kunde': 
            var input = $("#textBoxKunde").dxTextBox("option", "value");
            alert(input);
```

As in the devExtreme API documentation described, the code `$("#textBoxKunde").dxTextBox("option", "value");` should get the input-value of the textbox.

Now the strange thing:

- This works all fine in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox but in Internet Explorer 9, I cant read out the input value, instead I get null value.
- Much more strange is, I cant read out the value with IE 10 but when I turn on the developer tools in IE10 (same in IE-Edge), then I can suddenly read out the value.

I have already posted this problem on the DevExtreme Support Ticket, but I couldn't get a clue.

Does anyone have an idea of this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I have got an answer from the devextreme support team and this issue is solved now.

The solution was to add the ValueChangeEvent with the "keydown" Keyword, to get this work in IE9+

```
<div class="dx-field">
                <div class="dx-field-label">Kunde</div>
                <div class="dx-field-value">
                    @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBox()
                        .ID("textBoxKunde")
                        .OnEnterKey("function(e) { showPopup('Kunde') }")
                        .Placeholder("Name und/oder Vorname des Kunden eingeben...")
                        .ValueChangeEvent("keydown")
                        )
                </div>
            </div>
```